# How to confine img dimensions to its parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the "Nelson Mazda" png to fit within the limits of the navbar, but it's showing larger than the navbar as you can see in the screenshot. I tried setting the `max-height` and `max-width` of `.brand-logo` to 100%, but this doesn't seem to be fixing it. What am I missing?

Note: `nav-wrapper` is set to the same height as the navbar, so setting `.brand-logo`'s height to 100% of it should theoretically work, right?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
 <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <div class="navbar-fixed" id="nav">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <!-- Site name -->
                <a href="/" class="brand-logo"><span class="tighter"><img src="images/NelsonMazdaLogo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);

    .brand-logo,
    ul a {
        color: $black;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    .brand-logo {
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;

        .tighter {
            letter-spacing: -3px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI that doesn't look like valid `css`. Assuming its `scss`?

Comment: also, your html isn't valid: `span` tag isn't closed.

Comment: Remove the font weight and letter spacing as there is no text in this element from your snippet. Also add height to the parent then fix the image to the height only of the parent. If you set a width too on the image your aspect ratios can get effected of the rendered image.

Answer (score 3):

set `max-height` and `max-width` on the `img` itself

```
.brand-logo img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your outer nav has to have a height or width.

See these examples:
http://codepen.io/bootstrapped/details/KwYGwq/

```
.brand-logo {
    height: 50px; /* set to height you want image to be constrained to */
}

.brand-logo img {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Plus you have a random span tag that isn't closed.

```
 <div class="navbar-fixed" id="nav">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <!-- Site name -->
                <a href="/" class="brand-logo">
                    <span class="tighter"><img src="images/NelsonMazdaLogo.png"></span><!-- missing closing span tag -->
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

The key thing to think about is when you say 100% you have to think, 100% of what exactly? It needs to be inside a parent or grandparent element that has an actual height.

**Also if your image itself wasn't cropped properly it could be adding transparent space around the logo. If the above solution doesn't work, try downloading your image and cropping it to make sure it's actually cropped to the logo edges.**

You can also try [object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/):

```
object-fit: contain;
width: 100%;
```